# Аномальное поведение nodej и MySQL, потеря связи

Tags: mysql, node.js, gentoo

Встретился с аномальным поведением NodeJS и MySQL. Вопрос очень специфический, буду рад любым догадкам.

В общих словах структура работы следующая. Скрипт сервера на NodeJS подключается к MemcacheQ, читает очередь и если там что то появляется, выполняет запрос на выборку в MySQL + несколько запросов на добавление информации в таблицу лога.

Примерно два раза в месяц случается следующее. В какой то момент перестает выполняться код обработки информации запроса.

```
my.query(select_query, function(error, result, fields) {
  // код обработки информации, полученной из запроса
});
```

Делал вывод console.log(my) перед запросом и сравнивал, штатную и проблемную ситуацию. Разница была в том, что появлялось значение "Queue, Queue, ..., Queue" в одном из параметров. Сейчас не скажу уже точно, не сохранился лог. Буду ставить еще раз, т.к. вопрос оставлялся в связи с расставленными приоритетами.

Создание подключения:
var my = require(script_path+'/node_modules/mysql2').createConnection({user: dbuser,  password: dbpass, database: dbname, host: dbhost});
Сначала был mysql просто, потом использовал mysql2. Изменение не принесло успехов.

Дальше включил обрабатку ошибок:
my.on('error', function(err) {

```
    if(err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') { // Connection to the MySQL server is usually

        console.log('Lost connection MySQL Database');
        console.log('db error', err);
        sighandle();

    } else {                                      // connnection idle timeout (the wait_timeout

        console.log('Database disconnect. Another error');
        console.log('db error', err);
        sighandle();

    }
```

});

Думал поймаю что-нибудь, но ничего не прилетело. Такое чувство что есть некий параметр, дойдя до которого забивается очередь и запросы не выполняются.

Причем на этом же сервере работает apache+PHP+MySQL который читает и пишет в эту БД. В момент, когда появляется нештатная ситуация, веб интерфейс (apache+PHP+MySQL) работает корректно.

По нагрузке, примерно в 1 секунду NodeJS скрипт читает из MemcacheQ порядка 20 раз. Таких скриптов запущено порядка 15-20. БД размером порядка 300Гб.

В свое время как разбирался с проблемой, делал на сервере обновление пакетов через emerge -NuavD world (сервер гентушный). Не помогло.

Пробовал обновлять nodejs с версии 4 сначала на 6ую, потом пропатчил файлы и смог обновится на 7.9. Пока на восьмую не переходил.

Еще есть момент, когда делалась архивация старой информации и выполнялось куча запросов на удаление и добавление информации (думаю 200-250 млн запросов) в этом месяце сбой произошел гараздо раньше, чем через 15 дней..

Все случилось именно после переезда на новый сервер. На старом все было норм.
Старый: Intel® Xeon® E5-1650 v2, 128Gb DDR4, 2Tb SATA
Новый: Intel® Xeon® E5-1650 v3, 256Gb DDR4, 480SSD DataCenter Ed
Но в момент переезда все версии MySQL и nodejs были одинаковые. Существенное отличие в жестких.

Понимаю, что сложно однозначно дать ответ. Но может будут хоть какие-то предположения. Я сделал автоматический перезапуск, когда это случается. Но из-за особенностей системы простой все равно составляет пару минут. За эти пару минут прилетает 100-200 запросов. И доставляются неудобства пользователям.

Хочется вернуться к этому вопросу, может кто нибудь чего нибудь подскажет. 
Вывод console.log(my) поставил сейчас, но след. падение будет через примерно 10-12 дней..

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно отваливается коннект к MySQL по таймауту. Почитай про  pool conneсt https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections, мне помогло в похожей ситуации

Таймаут регулируется строкой db.query(`SET SESSION wait_timeout = 604800`);
Если поставишь цифру меньше, сможешь быстрее отловить свою ошибку

Comment: Уже и не думал, что кто нибудь ответит на вопрос. Обязательно протестирую этот момент и отпишусь. Спасибо